# I should have 500gb of space, but I can only use 250

Tags: ubuntu, mount, ssd

I bought dedicated server and they told me that I have 2 ssds (2x250GB) but when I do 
df -h

I see

```
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                              32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs                            6.3G   17M  6.3G   1% /run
/dev/md2                         197G   85G  103G  45% /
tmpfs                             32G     0   32G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                             32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1                         488M  373M   90M  81% /boot
tmpfs                            6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1001
```

and here is output when I do fdisk -l

```
...

Disk /dev/sdb: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xcddb903b

Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           2048  67110911  67108864    32G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2       67110912  68159487   1048576   512M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3       68159488 488395119 420235632 200.4G fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x9867791d

Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           2048  67110911  67108864    32G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2       67110912  68159487   1048576   512M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3       68159488 488395119 420235632 200.4G fd Linux raid autodetect


...
```

and

```
 # sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME    FSTYPE              SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda                       232.9G
├─sda1  linux_raid_member    32G            rescue:0
│ └─md0 swap                 32G [SWAP]
├─sda2  linux_raid_member   512M            rescue:1
│ └─md1 ext3              511.4M /boot
└─sda3  linux_raid_member 200.4G            rescue:2
  └─md2 ext4              200.3G /
sdb                       232.9G
├─sdb1  linux_raid_member    32G            rescue:0
│ └─md0 swap                 32G [SWAP]
├─sdb2  linux_raid_member   512M            rescue:1
│ └─md1 ext3              511.4M /boot
└─sdb3  linux_raid_member 200.4G            rescue:2
  └─md2 ext4              200.3G /
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on here ... :/

I have this server running for like half year but I noticed this today, can this be fixed so I could use all 500gb without loosing current data on disk?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your two SSDs are *mirrored* using the `md` (linux software raid) driver, so that if one fails, you will still have your data.  You *can* reformat the drives and have 500G of storage space (if your provider allows and assists), but you would (1) need to back it all up somewhere if you don't want to lose the data, and (2) permanently lose the safety of mirroring.

Personally, I would consider this a positive feature of your hosting provider, not a problem, *especially* if they monitor drive status and replace failed raid members before you experience data loss.  Check your hosting agreement for details.